# How to filter input values for percentile using SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation like this:

```
scala> val values = Seq((7,-1),(null,null),(1,0),(null,3),(2,5),(-1,null)).toDF("price","size")

scala> values.createOrReplaceTempView("mydata")

scala> sqlContext.sql("select percentile(price,0.5), percentile(size,0.5) from mydata").show()
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|percentile(price, CAST(0.5 AS DOUBLE), 1)|percentile(size, CAST(0.5 AS DOUBLE), 1)|
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1.5|                                     1.5|
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to filter the values for `price` and `size` based on some condition? For example let's say I want to include only values > 0. In Postgres I can do something like this:

```
select
   percentile_cont (0.5) within group (order by price) filter (where price > 0),
   percentile_cont (0.5) within group (order by size) filter (where size > 0)
from (values (7,-1),(null,null),(1,0),(null,3),(2,5),(-1,null)) T(price,size);

 percentile_cont | percentile_cont
-----------------+-----------------
               2 |               4
```

Anything similar for SparkSQL?

Comment: You can filter in dataframe as `values.filter($"size" gt 0).createOrReplaceTempView("mydata")`

Comment: That is like put a `where` in the query and it affects both parameters (`price`, `size`) but only at the condition of one (`size`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself:

```
sqlContext.sql("select percentile(case when price > 0 then price else null end,0.5) as median_price, percentile(case when size > 0 then size else null end, 0.5) as median_size from mydata").show()
+------------+-----------+
|median_price|median_size|
+------------+-----------+
|         2.0|        4.0|
+------------+-----------+
```